# Multiple related models single controller

Tags: yii, models, controllers

The issue I'm having is related to multiple models in a single controller/view in Yii. 
Specifically I can't figure out how to have a search bar for my related model in the the admin and search views with Gii generated CRUD.

I have two models "Recipes" and "RecipeSteps"

This is my Recipes relations

```
public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
        'recipeSteps' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'RecipeSteps', 'recipe_id'),
        );
    }
```

I can already create and update using the related models the issue comes in under the search I can see the related model "RecipeSteps" in the results because I added it into my Gridview like so:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'recipes-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        //'recipe_id',
        'recipe_name',
        'recipe_description',
        'recipeSteps.instructions',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

However I need to figure out how to add in the search bar above the "instructions" field so that filed can be searched as well.

I need to figure out how to add "instructions" to my form.

```
  <div class="wide form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl($this->route),
    'method'=>'get',
)); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->label($model,'recipe_name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'recipe_name',array('size'=>11,'maxlength'=>11)); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->label($model,'recipe_description'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'recipe_description',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Search'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- search-form -->
```

Recipe Search Function in Recipes

```
public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        //$criteria->compare('recipe_id',$this->recipe_id,true);
        $criteria->compare('recipe_name',$this->recipe_name,true);
        $criteria->compare('recipe_description',$this->recipe_description,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
```

and in Index and Admin in RecipesController

```
/**
 * Lists all models.
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Recipes');
    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}

/**
 * Manages all models.
 */
public function actionAdmin()
{
    $model=new Recipes('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['Recipes']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['Recipes'];

    $this->render('admin',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

I know this should be easy but I can't seem to figure out how to wrap my head around it I have read every piece of documentation I could find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to alter your search and column definition to work with the relation.
You need to use with(), columns filter().

Read this topic:

[Yii - Search filter of a relations field through cgridview](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/9083-search-filter-of-a-relations-field-through-cgridview/)

Comment: I've been looking all over for this, thanks for the great link on filtering/searching relations through a yii grid view.